# RadioButton will not change panel display when selected

Tags: vb.net

Hello I'm trying to get this radiobutton to change during panel display but it will not. I want it to change back in forth regardless of the order that it is selected but I'm having some difficulties. I'm aware that this is an easy fix but if anyone can help I will really appreciate it.

```
Public Sub RadioButton()

    If RadioButton1.Checked Then
        Panel2.Visible = True
    End If
    If RadioButton2.Checked Then
        Panel3.Visible = True
    End If
    If RadioButton3.Checked Then
        Panel4.Visible = True
    End If
    If RadioButton4.Checked Then
        Panel5.Visible = True
    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: VB.NET IsNot VBA.  Pick one

Comment: vb.net. Sorry about that.

Comment: `Panel2.Visible = RadioButton1.Checked`

Comment: Its still not working. It will not switch between panels.

Comment: Good first question. Includes code,Reproducable, states desired behaviour and what is actually happening. Keep asking them just like that.

Comment: A little note for the future: If you want to execute code when you interact with a control or when classes or controls change, you use events. Such as when you click a button you use the `Click` event.

Comment: Thank you! I will definitely remember that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds almost as if your panels are layered on top of each other - First thing to check is that none of the panels are children of another None of the panels effectively  sub panels of any others? This can happen very easily if you're moving panels around using drag and drop in the form designer.

From the Visual Studio View menu, click on View>Other Windows>Document Outline

This will bring up a Visual Studio tab showing all your controls on the form. Have a look at the Panel controls. If any are below another and are indented - like this :-

[image]

Panel5 is a child of Panel2. To correct this, drag Panel5 to just underneath Form1. Or - at the top of the tab. you can see a left,right,up and down arrow. Click the indented panel and then click the left arrow.

Do this for any other indented panels.

Next - you code. It should work fine if your panels aren't on top of each other, but if they're on top of each other, then you may also need to bring the Panel to the front of the pile -

```
Panel2.BringToFront
```

Hopefully this should solve the problems.

Comment: ..Thanks for the help. I was able to get it working. The panels were a layered as child. Once I made the move along with adding the Checked.Changed everything works fine! Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

I'm guessing you want to switch panels' visibility based on which radio button is selected. The problem is that you only make those panels visible but never not visible (i.e. when one becomes visible, others should not be visible). Change your code to:

```
Panel2.Visible = RadioButton1.Checked
Panel3.Visible = RadioButton2.Checked
Panel4.Visible = RadioButton3.Checked
Panel5.Visible = RadioButton4.Checked
```

Comment: Its still not working. I added the the code and it still will not switch between panel. Please help.                                                  Panel2.Visible = RadioButton1.Checked
Panel3.Visible = RadioButton2.Checked
Panel4.Visible = RadioButton3.Checked
Panel5.Visible = RadioButton4.Checked

Comment: How do you call `RadioButton` sub?

Comment: I just call it RadioButton. I have a larger App that I'm working on and I ran into this problem with the radio buttons switching back and forth between panels therefore I created a Test App to try and figure out what the problem is but I'm still having issues. I'm not sure why it wouldn't switch between panels.

Comment: Can someone please help me with this issue?

Comment: To be honest, I'm struggling to understand what exactly is the issue. You should probably expand your question and explain everything in more detail and provide more code.

Comment: I have a 4 panels layered on top of each other. When a radio button is checked it is suppose to display the panel. Unfortunately it will not display the panels when selected. I have 4 panels for each radio button. I'm just trying to get the radio button to display each panel when selected.

Comment: @Tom : One note for you: `How do you call the RadioButton sub?` means he's asking how you **execute it**, not what name you've given it.

Comment: @Tom : Secondly, you could have use of the `CheckedChanged` event that the RadioButtons have got.

Comment: Thanks Guys! It's now working. Due to the fact that the panels were layered on top of each other making some panels a child of another panel. Using the Document Outline I was able to move the panels making each panel a parent. I made the move and added the CheckedChanged and now it works. Thanks!!!!!!

Answer (score 1):

Do you even handle the RadioButtons' events?

You get use of the `CheckedChanged` event for this:

```
Private Sub RadioButtons_CheckedChanged(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles RadioButton1.CheckedChanged, RadioButton2.CheckedChanged, RadioButton3.CheckedChanged, RadioButton4.CheckedChanged
    Panel2.Visible = RadioButton1.Checked
    Panel3.Visible = RadioButton2.Checked
    Panel4.Visible = RadioButton3.Checked
    Panel5.Visible = RadioButton4.Checked
End Sub
```

**Read more:** [CheckedChanged Event - MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.radiobutton.checkedchanged(v=vs.110).aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-2)

Comment: Thanks Visual Vincent. It's now working!! You guys are the best!

Comment: @Tom : Always make sure you handle those events ;). Please mark the post that solved it for you as the accepted answer by pressing the green tick on it's left.